# Application Request Routing (ARR)

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, arr

I am in the process on installing a IIS on Win2008, which shall power PHP websites.

I am not familiar with "Application Request Routing". Does it make sense to install this module, when the plan is only to run php-sites?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is a single server and if you're running PHP on IIS where it's installed and configured as per the guidelines ([PHP non-threadsafe build + FastCGI](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/246/using-fastcgi-to-host-php-applications-on-iis/)) then I can't really see a reason to be adding ARR into the mix unless....

- you have Apache for Windows installed and are running your PHP applications in Apache but want to use ARR as a reverse proxy
- You wish to take advantage of some of the [caching features available](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/570/application-request-routing-version-2-overview/) in ARR

I'd leave it out until you start to hit problems that can be solved using ARR.